# Unable to deploy my solution in SharePoint 2013

Tags: solution-deployment, 2013

Hi I am using SP2013 stand-alone version. I am trying to deploy a solution in SharePoint 2013, I have successfully added the solution to solution store, but whenever I try to deploy the solution, timer job gets created but the timer job do not deploy the solution i.e. if i refresh the central admin page once it show deploying the solution, but after few mins when i refresh the page, it shows 'not deployed', and i also checked logs for any error but could not find any related to this, I tried PowerShell, STSADM & Central Admin, all with same result (yes i tried force also)

Some extra information -

- My solution needs GACDeployment, CASPolicies if that matters
- And my SharePoint Time Zone is different from my computer(which i have not fixed yet), I initially thought error is for this, but I tested with some other timer job to find it is not a problem

Any suggestion? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem, for some reason (I am yet to understand the reason)

```
stsadm -o deploysolution -name solutionname -url siteurl -allowGacDeployment -allowCasPolicies -immediate
```

is not working, in place of -immediate when i used -local (i am using a standalone version so -local does the work for me) i.e.

```
stsadm -o deploysolution -name solutionname -url siteurl -allowGacDeployment -allowCasPolicies -local
```

worked like a charm

Comment: For what it's worth, CAS policies are ignored in SharePoint 2013. All assemblies run with full trust: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163902.aspx